# Calling MATLAB from C without using Coder?

Tags: c++, ios, matlab, porting

So I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to call a MATLAB algorithm from C++ because we're trying to have the final application work on an iOS device.

Is there a way to call that MATLAB code that's been written from C++ without using MATLAB coder?

I've looked into using `coder.ExternalDependency` class and the official documentation but that uses MATLAB coder and I am trying to avoid that.

I also looked into using `feval` but all of the examples I could find online were only using pre-built in MATLAB functions like `gcd` - can I use `feval` with functions that I wrote myself to call from C++, or do they have to be functions already existing in MATLAB?

Or if anyone has any other suggestions on how to call a MATLAB function in a C++ program that would be great.

Comment: C *or* C++? Please pick one. C++ implies C code is valid, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: If you want to convert a MATLAB program into code that can run on a platform that is not (natively) supported by MATLAB itself, then MATLAB coder is _the_ way to do that. That's exactly what it's designed for. The MATLAB compiler will not work out for you because there is no MATLAB runtime on iOS. Failing that, you're left translating the code manually yourself.

Comment: Regarding your question on whether feval works with user-defined functions, yes it does. You can replace gcd in the example here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-c-1.html with your own function on path, and you should be able to generate an executable. However, as @Edric pointed out, you will need a MATLAB runtime in order to run this and as that is not an option in iOS, MATLAB Coder is the way to go. Why can you not use MATLAB Coder ?